# OpenVPN,EasyRSA :system was unable to find the specified registry key or value

Tags: windows, openvpn, rsa

I've installed (as Admin) latest version of OpenVPN (2.4.7-I603) on Windows 2012 x64. I've checked on installer EasyRSA 2. Then trying to generate the certificate go in path ..\program files\OpenVPN\easy-rsa\ open command prompt(as Admin) run

```
 init-config.bat
```

got :

> 1 file copied

then I run `vars.bat` and got:

> system was unable to find the specified registry key or value

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

solved using  [EasyRSA 3](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/releases) and steps from [here](https://www.sys-dev.cat/blog/3/) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/960657/create-firebird-3-vpn-secure-connection)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and for me I had to change the **vars.bat** since the version that gets shipped uses the default 32 bit switch when it should be 64bit registry option.  Look for this line (probably line 7) and it might work:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\OpenVPN"') DO set "PATH=%PATH%;%%b\bin"
```

to this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\OpenVPN" /reg:64') DO set "PATH=%PATH%;%%b\bin"
```