# Secure port accessing with Open VPN

Tags: openvpn, firebird

I've created a secure connection for Firebird 3(an open-source SQL relational database management system) using steps from [there](https://serverfault.com/a/960676/516695)

now I can connect from a client to server using Open VPN connection:there is a IP assigned for the server and I can connect to database using Firebird default port (3050)
It is possible to secure port 3050,only to be accessed only by VPN connections?

now It is allowed from the server firewall.if I block it from firewall no connection can access data.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set up Firebird to listen on the VPN interface only (using the `RemoteBindAddress` config directive), so it won't be available on other interfaces at all. This has the caveat that the VPN must be up in order for Firebird to be able to start (as it needs to bind to the virtual interface OpenVPN sets up).

Alternatively, you can setup the firewall on the computer to accept connections to Firebird's port only from a specific subnet (specifying the VPN subnet of course).